# emacsclient dialog on Windows

Tags: windows, emacs, emacsclient

I'm using EmacsW32 from http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsW32. EmacsClient works great - opening a file with it always uses an existing emacs. However, starting emacs for the first time opens a dialog with the text "Waiting for emacs server to start...", which is very annoying. Is there any way to suppress this dialog, or at least automatically dismiss it when it connects?

[EDIT] The issue is starting emacsclientw for the first time pops up this dialog, which connects to emacs-server, but then does not close. I'm looking for a way to make this dialog close once it connects, or not show up in the first place. It this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's been an update, or if I'm just impatient, but it appears as if the dialog closes itself, after a few seconds delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try an `-a` switch. `-a` is used to set a fall-back editor. In Windows you can't run emacs with `--daemon` flag, so if you run emacsclient like `emacsclient -a emacs` (given it is in your `PATH`) and you've set up emacs-server, then the first run of the emacsclient will start emacs server and all subsequent runs will use that server.